# Is it bad practice to store ordered list html tag inside mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been researching about this for quite some time and have found no exact answer to this question. I am asking strictly for ordered list element which is

```
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

tag elements to be stored in mysql db, and if it is bad practice, what is the good way to perform this ?

example of data to be stored in mysql db:

```
"Get the latest products here
Price starts from $$$
Specs:
<ul>
    <li>Specs</li>
    <li>Specs</li>
    <li>Specs</li>
</ul>"
```

All kinds of enlightenment are greatly welcomed. Thx

Comment: Don't store html tags in the database, you store just the data. Then your code (php) will put it togheter on your application with the order you chose.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content Read it, Live it, Love it -J

Comment: I love how no one has pointed out this is an UNordered list yet.

Comment: maybe I asked the wrong question and explained it rather badly, here is what I am actually asking.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305303/how-to-store-value-that-consist-of-string-and-has-a-list-into-mysql-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it's bad form or not isn't the question.  It's whether or not it is efficient, and whether or not the price of coding the efficiency is worth the gain.

Without knowing the rest of the application there are four ways to handle it off the top of my head.

- The way you are handling, but the cost is a SQL query every time you want that piece of HTML.
- Caching in memory using something like memcache, but depending on how many fragments you may run out of memory.
- Caching to a hard disk file, but need to regenerate the file when the tree changes.
- Regenerate the HTML every time it's needed. May be faster for smaller elements.

Comment: ok thank you for your explanation, actually I am asking how to achieve this, because I can't loop through all values and treat them the same way as some values has one or more lists inside it while some may not contain any list at all, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305303/how-to-store-value-that-consist-of-string-and-has-a-list-into-mysql-database . here maybe you will have a clearer picture of what I am trying to do..

Answer (score 1):

If your ordered list is mostly static (not likely to change) then it is best to keep it in the HTML layer. If it dynamic (likely to change) then you should keep the data items in any data store you wish.
As @unni Babu suggested keep the values separate and use a php loop to stuff the values in.

Answer (score 0):

> Why saving tags when its better only to save values inside tags .
>  I mean save values inside tags to db table. 
> Then Retrieve those values and display it using a php loop. 
> its better
> time saving
>  consumes less space. 
> Easy to insert and update

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that storing raw HTML in a database is bad practice, especially when, depending on the implementation of this, a user has the potential to go into the developer tools and manually add something malicious such as:

```
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  ...
  <script>alert("malicious code!");<script>
</ul>
```

Security risk aside, a better way to store the data is to put the `textContent` (as opposed to the `innerHTML`) of each `<li>` in your unordered list into an array and submit that instead.