# How to store value that consist of string and has a list into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Data Example to be inserted into mysql db:

```
value 1:
"some text some text some text,
 some random number 123455,
 unordered list:
 <ul>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
 </ul>";

value 2:
"some text some text,
 there are 2 unordered list here:
 <ul>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
   <li>some list</li>
   <li>some list</li>
 </ul>
 and some more text and much more text";
```

These are just an example of the value that I want to insert into mysql db, where some values have one or more list and texts while some others may not contain list. Since it is bad to insert list html tag into mysql db, and I can't loop all values and give them the list tag since some values does not even have a list inside it, what is the simplest and efficient solution to do this?

All suggestions are greatly welcomed. Thx

Comment: how about using ajax?

Comment: Given that the maximum row size *across all columns* in MySQL is [65,535 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) you will quickly hit your limit trying to store html. Strip it down to the parts you *really* need, remove the parts that would be nice to have.

Comment: I know I am not trying to store html, I am asking how to loop through all values and detect which values has list in it and display them as a list while those values that doesn't have a list to display it normally.

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the data before inserting it ... and when you want to read the data you must decode it again... also in the db you must make the column data type as a text ...
if you are using php there is a function encode and a decode function ... 
or you can use something like serialize and de-serialize

Answer (score 0):

To do that clean you should make 3 tables. one with and item ID and the Text. One with an an ID for the list, and of course the item ID as FK. And one table with all list item (id, list item value, and list ID as FK).